# How can I choose the previous td from the last tr in table with using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I want to select and change the previous tds from the last tr in table but I could not. How can I do this with use jQuery?

[image]

select prev tr with;

```
$(".tbl tr:last-child").prev()
```

but how can I select childs of prev tr?

http://jsfiddle.net/dba7v/1/

Comment: You want to select all cells from the second to last row?

Comment: You got your answer, but, I think that the **main** lesson from this question you can learn, is [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method in jQuery. It's really useful, for example in your case: `$(".tbl tr:last-child").prev().find('td')`, It's like the `$` usage, but it will search in current matched set, not the whole document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(".tbl tr:last-child").prev().children()`

or simple `$(".tbl tr:nth-last-child(2) > td")`